# /faq#benice redirects to /help

Tags: bug, status-completed, etiquette, help-center

`/faq#benice` is currently redirecting to the main help page rather than to a specific one.

It should re-direct to `/help/behavior` the same as `/faq#etiquette` does. The "be nice" part is the second paragraph on this page.

Could you be nice?

Comment: Only if you say "please". :P

Comment: Ouch, completely set myself up for that didn't I? I _knew_ I should have put a smiley face on the end! Please be nice @Laura :-).

Comment: It's on my list of stuff to fix this week. Nice catch.

Comment: @Laura: I would have gone for cherries on top, but your loss.

Comment: Who the devil is _Bénice_?

Comment: Whoever you want her to be @Grant :-). It's normally spelt Bernice though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/faq#benice and /faq#behonest should now redirect to the behavior page in the Help Center.

Comment: +1 because http://stackoverflow.com/faq#benice is working, -1 because http://stackoverflow.com/faq#behonest is not working (still redirecting to the default /help page)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Hmm...I will look into that.

Comment: Just curious, as you're not a developer (i.e. programmer) how you do this? You have some internal "admin panel"?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd For this particular thing, "looking into it" means verify that the redirect is not working, then poke the developer responsible to ask him to fix it. ;)

Comment: Oh, I see. Usually the dev is posting here, so I got bit confused. :-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I'm trying to stay on top of the meta feedback for this project so the dev team can focus on writing code (especially since some of the initial stuff was trivial and I could fix myself).

Comment: Well, if you can write JS you can fix this one as well. :)